# Minimum hamming distance of concatenated codewords

Tags: coding-theory

So here is the question and I am trying to find a proof for the minimum hamming distance d3:

Let $C_1$ be a $(n_1, M, d_1)$ q-ary code and $C_2$ a $(n_2, M, d_2)$ q-ary code.
Assume that we have named the codewords:

$$C_1 = {w_1, w_2, . . . , w_M }$$
$$C_2 =  {v_1, v_2, . . . , v_M }$$
Define the new code $C_3$ as the set of words $wivi$ for $i = 1, . . . , M$ . Find with
justification the parameters $n$, $M$, $d$ for the code $C_3$. (The data may not be enough
to determine the distance d of the new code C3 precisely. But you can say that d is
greater than some number. Which number?)

This is what I have:

Assume $$w_i, w_j \in C1$$ s.t $$d(wi, wj) = d1$$
Then, $$d(wivi, wjvj) = d1 + d(vi, vj)$$, so $$d(wivi, wjvj) >= d1 + 1$$
Assume $$vk, vl \in C2$$ s.t $$d(vk, vl) = d2$$
Then, $$d(wkvk, wlvl) = d2 + d(vk, vl)$$, so $$d(wkvk, wlvl) >= d2 + 1$$
By above, $$d3 >= max\{d1, d2\} + 1$$

Thank you

Comment: To show that you understand the prescribed construction you should begin with the $n$ and $M$ parameters. You can say more about the minimum distance. And you will benefit from taking a look at [the local guide to using MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619)

Comment: I already figured out $n$ and $M$

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of concatenation as it is used here? What is the meaning of the word $w_iv_i$? How do you calculate the Hamming distance between $w_iv_i$ and $w_jv_j$?

Comment: isnt it just $d(w_iw_j)+d(v_iv_j)$?

Comment: Yes (assuming you accidentally dropped the commas in-between). Why do you underestimate those two terms down to $1$ in turn?

Comment: @All the present and future readers of this question: This question uses a non-standard meaning of *a concatenated code*. I assume this definition is private to whoever designed the (sensible) exercise. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_error_correction_code) for the standard definition of concatenation of codes. There are also other useful ways of combining an inner code and an outer code, caveat reader.

Comment: wait, it should be $d(wi,wj)+d(vi,vj) = d1 + d2$ right? Since the minimum hamming distance of $d(vi,vj)$ regardless of its position should be $d2$ and not 1

Comment: Correct. :-) ${}$

Comment: For full credit: find an example where $d_1+d_2$ is never achieved, and the actual minimum Hamming distance is higher :-)